# UITapGestureRecognizer calling another class

Tags: objective-c, ios, class, uitapgesturerecognizer

I am having an issue setting up a `UITapGestureRecognizer` calling a shared class across my app.

Basically I have a bunch of images that if tapped will popup another view with that image and comments. Instead of using `initWithTarget` using `self` I want to call the function from a shared class that can be loaded into each type of Navigation Controller.

I am able to initialize `ImageClass *imageClass = [[ImageClass alloc]init]` and call the functions fine by `[imageClass DoThis]` however when I add it to a UITapGestureRecognizer the app crashes.

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:imageClass action:@selector(DoThis)];
```

Also if I include the `DoThis` function and `initWithTarget:self` everything works as expected however I'd like to not write the `DoThis` function into every View Controller if possible I'd like it to fire directly from the `UITapGestureRecognizer`.

Thanks in advance for any insight you can give me into what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: I think imageClass is deallocated when the "DoThis" is fired on tapping. Can you enable Zombie and check it is not the case ?

Comment: I am using ARC and it does appear to be getting deallocated. I'll start investigating that path.

Answer (score 0):

Alright basically I the imageClass object was getting deallocated every time a new image appeared.  I moved that logic to the controller and all started working fine.

Thanks for helping out MSK!