# App crashes when setting a class to UITapGestureRecognizer's target instead of 'self'

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uitapgesturerecognizer, ios8.1

The below code works when I set 'self' as target to the instance of UITapGestureRecognizer but when I set it to 'SkinViewTransitionHelper' instance the app crashes and the Xcode doesn't show any helpful information, actually nothing at all and when the app crashes the control(the green indicator I mean) goes to AppDelegate. Also, the stack trace is empty just showing some threads that are not relevant to the crash. I did search a lot and reread the documentation of UIGestureRecognizer but did not help. What am I doing wrong? I'm coding the app in Xcode Version 6.2 (6C107a). Also, I'm testing the app in iOS simulator Version 8.2 (553.8). I also did check [UITapGestureRecognizer calling another class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12287217/uitapgesturerecognizer-calling-another-class)

```
/**
     Manages the view that contains logo and button.
     */
    class LaunchView: UIView {
        // MARK: Instance variables
        /** Logo image view */
        private var logoImageView:    UIImageView!
        /** x Button image view */
        private var xButtonImageView: UIImageView!

        // MARK: Designated Initializer

        /**
           Initialize LaunchView view with logo and button.

           :param: frame        Frame of this view
           :param: logoImage    Logo Image used at the top of the view
           :param: xButtonImage Button Image used at the bottom of the view
        */
        init(frame: CGRect, logoImage: UIImage, xButtonImage: UIImage){
            super.init(frame: frame)

            // Initialize the logoImageView
            logoImageView = UIImageView(frame: frame)
            // Set the image of logoImageView
            logoImageView.image = logoImage

            // Initialize the capriceButtonImage
            // Note: It's kinda hard coding the (x,y) values. Look for a generic way.
            xButtonImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: frame.size.width / 4 + 20, y: frame.size.height - 200, width: xButtonImage.size.width, height: xButtonImage.size.height))
            // Set the image of xButtonImageView
            xButtonImageView.image = xButtonImage

            // SingleTap recognizer for xButtonImageView
            // Note: Find a generic solution instead of writing method name in "". It's kinda horrible; Maybe I forget to write the name of function correctly.
            // Note: Still not possible in Swift. reflect() helps if we want information about properties.
            // Note: https://github.com/ksm/SwiftInFlux#reflection
            // FIXME: App crashes using SkinViewTransitionHelper() as target
            let singleTapGestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer = 
                   UITapGestureRecognizer(target: SkinViewTransitionHelper(), action: "handleGesture:")

            // works like a charm if I remove the comment and comment above line
            // let singleTapGestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "handleGesture:")

            // Set the nunmber of taps required
            singleTapGestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
            singleTapGestureRecognizer.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1

            // Add tap gesture to xButtonImageView

            xButtonImageView.addGestureRecognizer(singleTapGestureRecognizer)

            xButtonImageView.userInteractionEnabled = true

            // Add logoImageView to the view
            self.addSubview(logoImageView)
            // Add xButtonImageView to the view
            self.addSubview(xButtonImageView)
        }

        required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
            fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
        }

        // func handleGesture(gestureRecongnizer: UIGestureRecognizer) {
            // if .Ended == gestureRecongnizer.state {
                // T0D0: Notify LaunchViewController of gesture
            // }
        // }
    }

    /**
    Handle gesture recognized by a UIView instance
    */
    class SkinViewTransitionHelper {
        // MARK: Gesture Handler

        /**
        Handle gesture recognized by a UIView instance
        */
        func handleGesture(gestureRecongnizer: UIGestureRecognizer) {
            println(__FUNCTION__)

            if .Ended == gestureRecongnizer.state {
                // TODO: Load SkinViewController
            }
        }
    }

import UIKit

class LaunchViewViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        println(self)
        println(__FUNCTION__)

       super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func loadView() {
        println(self)
        println(__FUNCTION__)

        // Set LaunchView as the view of LaunchViewViewController
        self.view = LaunchView(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds, logoImage: ImagesCatalog.Logo, xButtonImage: ImagesCatalog.xButton)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It crashes because `target` is a weak property of the `UITapGestureRecognizer` class and so the instance of `SkinViewTransitionHelper` is not retained by by the `UITapGestureRecognizer`.

Make a property of type `SKinViewTransitionHelper` and store an instance on it and set it to the `UITapGestureRecognizer` target.

```
class LaunchView {

    var skinViewHelper : SKinViewTransitionHelper!

     init(frame: CGRect, logoImage: UIImage, xButtonImage: UIImage){

         //Your code
         self.skinViewHelper = SKinViewTransitionHelper()
         let singleTapGestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer = 
                   UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self.skinViewHelper, action: "handleGesture:")
     }
}
```

Also mark the function you want to reference as selector with `@objc`

```
class SkinViewTransitionHelper {

    @objc func handleGesture(gestureRecongnizer: UIGestureRecognizer) {
        println(__FUNCTION__)

        if .Ended == gestureRecongnizer.state {
            // TODO: Load SkinViewController
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you instantiate SkinViewTransitionHelper a store its value into a variable (probably needs to be a class property) and then assign it as the target?

I think it's possible that you SkinViewTransitionHelper instance is deallocated after the 'target' assignment because there are no hard references to it anywhere.